# Problema com hora errada no PHP (America/Sao_Paulo)

Tags: php, datetime, data, timezone

Estou com uma aplicação rodando num ambiente de produção CentOS com PHP e Apache atualizados.

Percebi que os *logs* do CakePHP retornam um horário errado do definido no `php.ini` e também setado dentro do Bootstrap da aplicação por `date_default_timezone_set(..)`.

Tanto nos logs quanto no date do PHP o horário retornado é sempre **2 horas a menos**.

Por exemplo, agora é 15:35 e o php retorna como:

**20/01/2015 13:35:10 America/Sao_Paulo BRST**

O date do sistema operacional está em ordem, mostra na data certa, executa os crons no horário certo também.

O que pode estar ocorrendo?

Comment: O que você chama de "a hora do servidor está ordem"? Que ela está em horário UTC, ou seja, GMT, que está no horário universal? Pois bem, se for isto, a hora apresentada também está correta. 15:45 GMT equivale à 13:35 BRST. Ou você precisa fazer conversão ou usar a hora real do servidor no TZ que você deseja. Você não mostrou códigos usados para indicar como obteve os resultados que você falou então não posso detalhar mais.

Comment: Não uso CakePHP, mas com uma consulta no google, cheguei à uma [questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625181/how-do-i-set-default-timezone-in-cakephp) no StackOverflow em inglês que fala para setar o timezone no arquivo `config/core.php` na pasta da aplicação.

Comment: O codigo utilizado é um simples date() do PHP. O servidor esta em GMT(Tue Jan 20 18:09:28 GMT 2015)..talvez seria isso?

Comment: Exatamente, o servidor está em horário certo, o retorno está em horário certo, a única coisa errada é a interpretação do horário. Se sobrar tempo eu monto uma resposta sobre isto.

Comment: Seria bom informar qual é a diferença de horas do clock da placa mãe também, para fins de comparação (normalmente disponível ao configurar a BIOS ou equivalente).

Comment: PS: Não diretamente relacionado a esse problema, mas máquinas virtualizadas podem dar diferença nos minutos também, dependendo de como o sincronismo de clock está configurado. (Normalmente isto deve ser feito pelo ambiente de virtualização em vez do NTP convencional).

Comment: @Bacco que é a explicação para o erro que eu falo no final da minha resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por toda descrição do problema que eu li eu entendo que está havendo só uma interpretação errada de como usar a data.

Meu entendimento é de que o servidor está com o horário certo, pelo menos seu exemplos batem com os horário do Brasil no momento que você posta. Você está está interpretando que o horário está em GMT que é o horário universal, mas o horário do servidor está no horário `Brazil\East`, ele está usando o `-0200`. GMT usa o `0000`. Como o servidor interpreta que ela está em GMT, qualquer tentativa de usar outra *timezone* resultará no momento em 2 horas de erro. Então se o horário do servidor já é o horário que você quer, você não pode usar outra *timezone* que não seja a GMT.

Outra interpretação possível é que o horário do servidor está errado, já que ele está com a hora do Brasil mas está indicando que o horário é GMT. De fato, analisando estritamente, está errado mesmo. Quando você diz precisamente às 18:09 do horário brasileiro que seu servidor mostra `18:09 GMT` indica que está errado, porque às 18:09 do horário brasileiro o GMT correto é 20:09.

Você tem algumas opções:

- Se quer usar o horário brasileiro no servidor ajuste o *timezone* do servidor para ser BRST (terá que ajustar para BRT quando acabar o horário de verão, se o servidor não fizer automaticamente).
- Se quer manter o uso do GMT, coloque o horário correto do agora, coloque o horário de Londres e não o nosso.
- Ou ainda deixe do jeito que está e pare de configurar outros softwares para usar outro *timezone*, já que o que está no servidor é exatamente o horário que você quer. Ou seja, pare de configurar o PHP, seja no `ini`, seja com a função `date_default_timezone_set`.

A última solução não é a mais correta. Se tiver algum software que você não pode controlar a *timezone*, vai dar problema. Em compensação é a única forma de softwares mal feitos que não consideram a *timezone* funcionar corretamente.

Veja um [servidor com tudo correto](https://ideone.com/belruy) (apesar do horário não estar lá tão bem sincronizado na hora que eu testei :) ).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Date/TimeZone.php).