# Como definir date('d/m/Y H:i:s') com hora de Brasília ao invés de hora do servidor

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou gravando a data e hora no banco de dados com o *script*:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO admin_users (user_name, user_password_hash, user_email, user_data)
                        VALUES('" . $user_name . "', '" . $user_password_hash . "', '" . $user_email . "', '" . date('d/m/Y H:i:s') . "' );";
```

mas o horário é registrado do servidor, e não o de Brasília.
Como gravar a hora de Brasília?

Comment: Ué, é so arrumar a hora do servidor? Ou eu que não entendi a pergunta..

Comment: @Renan, se o servidor estiver na mesma faixa GMT de Brasília, não tem porque corrigir a hora, mas caso não estiver, a correção se faz necessária, podendo fazer uso dos fusos horários.

Comment: estou no servidor local wamp, quando hospedar terei problemas com hora?

Comment: Depende do local onde ele estiver. Se ele estiver em São Paulo, por exemplo, pode deixar o horário de Brasilia mesmo.

Comment: Seria isto? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47694/101?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Basta usar o [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) do php e definir o fuso-horário como o horário de Brasília, neste caso 'America/Sao_Paulo'. [Aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/timezones.php) você pode consultar a lista de Timezones Suportados.

OBS.: Se o seu servidor estiver no local do fuso-horário desejado(Ex.: São Paulo) você não precisa usar o `date_default_timezone_set`.

```
// DEFINE O FUSO HORARIO COMO O HORARIO DE BRASILIA
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
// CRIA UMA VARIAVEL E ARMAZENA A HORA ATUAL DO FUSO-HORÀRIO DEFINIDO (BRASÍLIA)
    $dataLocal = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', time());
```

Comment: Ou caso queira pode usar também o DateTime. $date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));

Answer (score 0):

Segue o código que eu uso.

```
$h = "3"; //HORAS DO FUSO ((BRASÍLIA = -3) COLOCA-SE SEM O SINAL -).
$hm = $h * 60;
$ms = $hm * 60;
//COLOCA-SE O SINAL DO FUSO ((BRASÍLIA = -3) SINAL -) ANTES DO ($ms). DATA
$gmdata = gmdate("m/d/Y", time()-($ms)); 
//COLOCA-SE O SINAL DO FUSO ((BRASÍLIA = -3) SINAL -) ANTES DO ($ms). HORA
$gmhora = gmdate("g:i", time()-($ms));
```