# Ajustar hora em string PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Minha hospedagem esta configurada para UTC (GMT 00:00) e não consigo alterar através do Mysql, devido bloqueios por ser um host compartilhado.
Meu código PHP traz resultados de data/hora de pedidos, mas ele esta com 3h acima (devido nosso GMT de Sao Paulo ser -03:00)

Tenho esta funçao e gostaria de corrigir nela esta diferença de -3 horas.

```
function converteDataHora($data, $hora=true){
    // Aqui pegamos a data, e dividimos ela em duas, usando a métodoExplode()
    $data = explode(" ", $data);

    // AQUI TEMOS AS DUAS PARTES
    $data1 = $data[0]; // DATA (xxxx-xx-xx)
    $data2 = $data[1]; // HORA (xx:xx:xx)

    // Agora dividimos a data em três partes, também usando o método Explode()
    $data1 = explode("-", $data1);

    $dia = $data1[2]; // Retorna o dia
    $mes = $data1[1]; // Retorna o mês
    $ano = $data1[0]; // Retorna o ano

    /* Como deve ter notado, dentro das variáveis existem o número de array, o 0(zero) trás o ano, 1 o mês e o 2 o dia para saber mais recomendo pesquisar sobre a função

    Agora vamos formatar a data, trazemos as strings, e a hora
    Aonde dia traz a string $data1[2]
    Aonde mês traz a string $data1[1]
    Aonde ano traz a string $data1[0]

    Como não precisamos "explodir" a hora trazemos ela normalmente através da string $data2

    */

    $data = $dia . "/" . $mes . "/" . $ano;

    if($hora==true)
        $data .=  " &agrave;s " . $data2;

    // Retornamos o valor
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplesmente sempre **grave** (`INSERT INTO`, `UPDATE`, `REPLACE`) **como UTC**, então esta ótimo o seu banco estar como UTC, porque se mudar o sistema de região ou mudar até de país e os horários estiverem como `America/Sao_Paulo` ou outro o sistema vai "quebrar".

No momento que for **LER** as linhas do banco você compensa a hora, pois qualquer hora se baseia no GMT ou UTC e assim basta ajustar a zona de tempo no PHP, como sugerido na outra resposta, mas sempre que for atualizar no banco acaso seja um horário manual você vai ter que converter a data e hora para UTC (no momento de gravar).

Para gravar no banco (se vier a gravar manualmente ao invés de usar as funções do mysql) pois o valor vem de um formulário pode fazer algo como (código **hipotético**):

```
$horario = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['horario_selecionado_pelo_usuario']);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO exemplo (horario) VALUES (?)');

$stmt->bind_param('s', $horario);

$stmt->execute();
```

As funções de data com o prefixo `gm` trabalham com o formato GMT/UTC (conforme a documentação https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) e desta forma você não precisa ficar ajustando na hora de gravar, use o `date_default_timezone_set` somente para exibir, passando os valores da hora no banco com `date()`, sem o prefixo `gm`:

```
if (!$stmt->bind_result($id, $horario)) {

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo 'ID: ', $id, '<br>';
        echo 'Horário: ', date('d/m/Y h:i', strtotime(horario)), '<br>';
    }

}
```

> Os códigos hipotéticos usados são baseados na API mySqli e não na PDO, mas é fácil adaptar, se tiver algum erro ou até exagero nos códigos me comunique, pois no momento não pude testar

---

Aliás, devo dizer que configurar de forma forçada uma zona horária pode ser algo complicado, se o sistema é pequeno tudo bem, mas se for uma empresa ou um site acessado por diversos estados do país seria melhor ajustar a timezone conforme a região do usuário (claro que isso é mais complicado)

Comment: Desta forma não deu, pois coloquei um echo dentro da pagina que faz o salvamento, e la ele atualiza a hora, mas quando salva no mysql, ele grava como data GMT 0 (3h a frente)

Comment: Caro @EvertonThomazi provavelmente você configurou algo errado ou não conseguiu aplicar a lógica sugerida na resposta, pode dar mais detalhes?

Comment: Isso que achei estranho, pois coloquei <?php date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo"); ?> no config.php do meu site, no php do carrinho (que faz o pedido), e coloquei um "echo date('H:i:s')" pra ver a hora, quando troquei o timezone pra outro aleatório, esta echo mudou, mas no gravar o pedido, ele salvou ainda como UTC

Comment: @EvertonThomazi depende de como esta gravando

Comment: @EvertonThomazi Desculpe, realmente foi confusão minha, ajustei o exemplo `$horario = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['horario_selecionado_pelo_usuario']);`

Answer (score 1):

Coloque no início do arquivo:
`<?php date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo"); ?>`

Aqui a lista das timezones suportadas:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

Leia mais sobre neste link:
[Como definir date('d/m/Y H:i:s') com hora de Brasília ao invés de hora do servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50338/como-definir-dated-m-y-his-com-hora-de-bras%C3%ADlia-ao-inv%C3%A9s-de-hora-do-servid)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver fazendo o seguinte, no MYSQL a coluna 'data' estava definida com "**current_timestamp()**", então deixei NULL e comecei enviar a data no meu site da seguinte forma > $data["data"]  = **date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');** que é o formato que eu preciso (YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS) / (AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)