# Mostrar próximo valor de uma Array com base no valor anteriormente encontrado

Tags: php

Não consigo mostrar o elemento da sequência de uma Array com horarios.

Criei uma variavel $hora que armazena a hora local, e um array com varios horarios $os, daí faço a busca por um horario igual, caso tenha ele mostra, mas se não tem quero mostrar o próximo horário.

Vejam o que ja fiz:

```
$hora = date('Hi');
$os = array('1632','1635','1638','1654','1642');

    if( in_array($hora, $os)){

        echo "Proximo onibus as : " . $hora;
    }else{

        echo  // Comparar e dar o valor subsequente ao valor da hora 
              // encontrada
    }

};
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: E se não houver valor subsequente? O que deve acontecer?

Comment: Na realidade esse array sera uma " tabela" com horarios de onibus, caso não ache devo colocar mais um else no final com alguma msg.

Ex: agora são 17:47 , suponhamos que o cara consultou e e o ultimo valor era 17:45, então ele mostra o proximo valor por ex 18:00 ..

Comment: Leo, veja este post: [Get Next](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9801618/1898543). Deve te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preste atenção com [diferenças de horários/timezones](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47635/problema-com-hora-errada-no-php-america-sao-paulo) com o servidor ou os valores guardados no banco.

Tente isso:

```
$hora = date('Hi');
$os = array('1632','1635','1638','1654','1642');

// pega o próximo
sort($os); // caso garanta que $os estará ordenado, pode tirar essa linha
$proximo = '';
foreach ($os as $h) {
    if ($h - $hora >= 0) {
        $proximo = $h;
        break;
    }   
}

// mostra mensagem
if (empty($proximo)) {
    echo "Não haverá mais ônibus após esse horário hoje";
} else {
    echo "Próximo ônibus: " . $proximo;
}
```

Comment: funcionou é isso mesmo que precisava! Obrigado!

Comment: @Leo :) de nada!

Answer (score 0):

Essa é a forma mais simples que encontrei:

```
<?php

$hora = date('Hi');
$os = array(1632,1635,1638,1654,1642,2200,2300,2305,2308,2310,2320,2330 );

foreach($os as $o){
// echo "<li>$o";
  if($hora == $o){
    echo "<p>O horário foi encontrado: " . $o ."</p>";
    break;
  }
  if($o > $hora){
    echo "<p>O horário não foi encontrado, mas o próximo é: ".$o." </p>";
    break;
  }

}

?>
```